# Alter Schema timing out on one particular Schema

Tags: sql-server, schema

I am trying to move a table from one schema to another.  I have tried this from table design and through TSQL with an `ALTER SCHEMA` statement (`ALTER SCHEMA SchemaName TRANSFER dbo.ObjectName`).

I can do this for any schema in my database except one now as it times out in the designer and runs forever in TSQL. It has 7-8 tables in it that I was originally able to put in the schema but now the schema appears locked.  How do I debug this?  I see nothing in the standard error logs.

Comment: The schema or table is locked by another process. You can run `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks` to see what is happening.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the help.   That sounds like that was exactly the problem.   A few hours later I was able to access and alter the schema just fine.  I share the database with a couple of other people so most likely they were doing something at that time causing the locks.